# Copy-Paste opens callback.php

Tags: aptana3

I have a problem with the latest version of Aptana (3.2) on MacOS Lion. Very often, when I copy-paste a bit of code (using cmd+C,cmd+V), it opens callback.php, and my code is pasted in it, which is not very convenient.

Do I do something wrong? Is it Mac version only? Is there some key hidden somewhere?

Thanks for your help!